# I need to change the layout for different uses

Tags: c#, nlog

I need to change the layout of my log file when writing log entries from an aspect. I will likely need to change other settings as well in time.

I have created two FileTargets that create the layout as I require.

```
    LoggingConfiguration config = new LoggingConfiguration();
    LoggingConfiguration aspectConfig = new LoggingConfiguration();

    FileTarget fileTarget = new FileTarget();
    fileTarget.Name = "fileTarget";
    fileTarget.Layout = "${longdate} ${machineName} ${callsite} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}";
    fileTarget.FileName = String.Format("{0}Admin.log", Config.DatabasePath);
    fileTarget.KeepFileOpen = false;


    FileTarget aspectTarget = new FileTarget();
    aspectTarget.Name = "aspectTarget";
    aspectTarget.Layout = "${longdate} ${machineName} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}";
    aspectTarget.FileName = String.Format("{0}Admin.log", Config.DatabasePath);
    aspectTarget.KeepFileOpen = false;


    LoggingRule rule2 = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, fileTarget);
    config.LoggingRules.Add(rule2);

    LoggingRule aspectRule = new LoggingRule("aspects", LogLevel.Trace, aspectTarget);
    aspectConfig.LoggingRules.Add(aspectRule);


    LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

There may be other changes/differences to come but that is besides the point at this stage.

Using the following works fine for the 'default or '*' config ie by using :

```
  var log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
  log.Fatal("##########################################");
```

What I want to do is be able to use the 'aspectRule' rather than the default '*' rule by calling logger and specifying the 'aspectRule'.

I had thought this would work:

```
  var log = LogManager.GetLogger("aspects");
  log.Fatal("########################################");
```

which is all well and good but I can't see how I define a new Logger called 'aspects' particularly as in code I don't even create a Logger called '*' :-)

Note that I am not using an XML config file and need a solution to use programatically.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I need to write 1 log entry as in this example:

```
  if (someCondition)
    logger.Fatal("#############"); // use layout in fileTarget
  else
    logger.Fatal("##############");  // use layout in aspectTarget
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: To answer your edited question, `LoggingRule rule2 = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, fileTarget)` will log **any** output to the log file.

If you want a specific output then you'll have to be specific with NLog.
For example, log anything ranging from `Trace` up to `Info` with a fileTarget ("*"), and have two other **specific** targets `aspects` and `rule2` with log levels from `Error` to `Fatal`.

Then you could log like this:

```
LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Debug( "Non-specific message" );
LogManager.GetLogger( "rule2" ).Fatal( "From rule2" );
LogManager.GetLogger( "aspects" ).Fatal( "From Aspects" );
```

--

You're creating two configurations `config` and `aspectConfig`, setting up both and eventually setting `LogManager.Configuration = config`.

Eventually `aspectConfig` is not being used. To resolve, remove all `aspectConfig` related code and fix the `acpects` line to this:

`config.LoggingRules.Add(aspectRule);`

Comment: What your suggesting is what I had originally. This means that when I execute log.Fatal("####") an entry is recorded twice in the log. My question was - how do I record just one entry. I have ameneded my question to make it clearer...

Comment: Thanks - that clarifies it well. It was the LogManager.GetLogger(????) that had me confused as to what to put in place of the ???? .

Comment: Yup, specific logger for a specific target. NLog is a really nice library. Enjoy.